# My custom collective.opengraph adapter isn't used by Plone

Tags: adapter, plone

I'm having problems telling Plone to use my custom adapter for [collective.opengraph's](https://github.com/collective/collective.opengraph) *viewlets.ATMetatags*.

I followed the instructions in the package's README and ended up with the following:

Here my theme's package folder structure:

```
.
├── adapters.py 
├── behaviors.py
├── behaviors.zcml
├── completer.hist
├── configure.zcml
├── __init__.py
├── interfaces.py
├── portlets
├── profiles
├── resources
├── testing.py
└── tests
```

Here's my *adapters.py* file:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from zope.interface import implements
from zope.component import getMultiAdapter, adapts

from collective.opengraph.interfaces import IOpengraphMetatags
from collective.opengraph.viewlets import ATMetatags, decode_str


class MyOpengraphMetatags(ATMetatags):

    implements(IOpengraphMetatags)
    adapts(ATMetatags)

    def __init__(self, context):
        print "MyOpengraphMetatags.__init__!"
        super(MyOpengraphMetatags, self).__init__(self, context)


    @property
    def image_url(self):
        """
            don't use the default plone logo !
        """
        return "test.png"

    @property
    def description(self):

        context = self.context.aq_inner
        portal_state = getMultiAdapter((context, self.request), name=u'plone_portal_state')
        current_language = portal_state.language

        description_fr = "fr"
        description_en = "en"
        description = description_fr if current_language == "fr" else description_en

        return decode_str(description, self.default_charset)

    @property
    def metatags(self):
        """
            Adding custom tags !
        """
        tags = super(MyOpengraphMetatags, self).metatags

        tags.update({
            "twitter:site": "@a-twitter-account"
        })

        return tags
```

And finally, my *configure.zcml* file:

```
<configure
    xmlns="http://namespaces.zope.org/zope"
    xmlns:i18n="http://namespaces.zope.org/i18n"
    xmlns:genericsetup="http://namespaces.zope.org/genericsetup"
    xmlns:plone="http://namespaces.plone.org/plone"
    i18n_domain="my.theme">

  <includeDependencies package="." />

  <!-- Include files -->
  <include file="behaviors.zcml" />

  <include package=".portlets" />

  <plone:static
    directory="resources"
    type="theme"
    />

  <genericsetup:registerProfile
      name="default"
      title="my.theme"
      directory="profiles/default"
      description="Installs the my.theme package"
      provides="Products.GenericSetup.interfaces.EXTENSION"
      />

  <!-- -*- extra stuff goes here -*- -->
  <adapter 
    for="collective.opengraph.viewlets.ATMetatags"
    factory=".adapters.MyOpengraphMetatags"
    provides="collective.opengraph.interfaces.IOpengraphMetatags"
  />

</configure>
```

My adapter is detected by Plone but not used at all.

I added `pdb.set_trace` and `print` instructions in there as well without success.

Adding those instructions within the `collective.opengraph` egg works though.

Am I forgetting a configuration somewhere ? Is the adapter tag in the appropriate *configure.zcml* file ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to override the adapter directly you can do this by overriding the already registered adapter. 
Your overrides.zcml could look like this:

```xml
<configure
    xmlns="http://namespaces.zope.org/zope"
    xmlns:i18n="http://namespaces.zope.org/i18n"
    i18n_domain="my.theme">

    <adapter 
        for="Products.ATContentTypes.interface.interfaces.IATContentType"
        factory=".adapters.MyOpengraphMetatags"
        provides="collective.opengraph.interfaces.IOpengraphMetatags"
        />

</configure>
```

Btw. the `for` attribute in your adapter registration needs to be a dotted name to a class which inherits from `Interface` (zope.interface.Interface). The adapter in collective.opengraph is registered for `Products.ATContentTypes.interface.interfaces.IATContentType`. This means the adapter is only available for objects which implements the `Products.ATContentTypes.interface.interfaces.IATContentType` interface (Usually archetypes based content types).

Also remove `implements(IOpengraphMetatags)` and `adapts(ATMetatags)` from `MyOpengraphMetatags`, since you already did this with the adapter registration. `adapts(ATMetatags)` makes no sense.

If you have your own not Archetype based content type, which implements it's own interface. You can register the adapter in your `configure.zcml`:

```xml
    <adapter 
        for="dotted.name.to.your.interface"
        factory=".adapters.MyOpengraphMetatags"
        provides="collective.opengraph.interfaces.IOpengraphMetatags"
        />
```

---

Here's the full solution in steps by OP:

1. Move the *adapter* tag to an *overrides.zcml* file and remove it from the *configure.zcml* file
2. Make sure the package you are overriding is added within your buildout packages
3. Run buildout
4. Start Plone in *fg* mode.

Comment: thank you for your recommandations and explanations. I'll try it in a couple of minutes !

Comment: I moved my *adapter* tag inside an overrides.zcml file that I've included in the configure.zcml and made the *for* attribute change. The following error now appears in the console: http://pastie.org/pastes/9745577/text?key=td0knff5rjo1qhvzj5aaqa I guess I'll have to make my own *interface* here.

Comment: You don't have to include the overrides.zcml in your main configure.zcml, this way it's treated as a regular zcml file. the overrides.zcml should be loaded automatically after you run buildout.